# Add a button in fornt of each row that send email to the a column email value

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, action, dynamic-rows

I have a form in front end that save vale in database and shown in the admin grid. I have an action button in front of each row so click of this button i want to get the rest of columns value.

I have following grid in admin:

```
 protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Name'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '10px',
        'index' => 'name',
        ));

    $this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Email'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'email',
        'width' => '50px',
        ));


    $this->addColumn('comment', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Comments'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'comment',
        ));

      $this->addColumn('action',
        array(
      'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Send Email'),
      'width' => '50',
      'type' => 'action',
      'getter' => 'getId',
      'actions' => array(
             array(
                  'caption' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Review Email'),
                  'url' => array('base'=> '*/*/view'),
                  'field' => 'id'
                )),
      'filter' => false,
      'sortable' => false,
      'index' => 'stores',
      'is_system' => true,
     ));
```

How i can do this for each row.

[image]

Comment: You want to display all values to admin or you want to send email?

Comment: want to send email to the ID in the column email onclik of the  button in the row..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller file in which the action for loading grid page is defined, add function mentioned below.

```
public function viewAction(){
    $request=$this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $modelData=Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/contacts')->load($request['id']);//This will fetch all data corresponding to a particular id. 

    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
            ->setToName($senderName)
            ->setToEmail($customerEmail)
            ->setBody($html)
            ->setSubject('Subject :')
            ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
            ->setFromName($senderName)
            ->setType('html');
    try{
        $mail->send();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Mail sent successfully');
    }
    catch(Exception $error)
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Comment: So how it will trigger on based of each row button that is in front of each? as shown in image it is "Review Email"

Comment: The 'actions' parameter in addColumn value will create URL like http://path/to/admin/controller/view/id/1/key/98awree045sdsd80/. It will add entity id value in the URL. In the above example, it is '1'.  This id value we are fetching using statement $id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

Comment: I got this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\extension-development\app\code\community\OptFirst\ReviewMyCompany\controllers\Adminhtml\EmailsController.php on line 24

Comment: Please provide the code that you are using to get collection for grid.

Comment: Here it is:  protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/contacts')->getCollection();
        //print_r($collection);
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

Comment: Please check I have updated load statement in my function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51372/discussion-between-xabby-and-piyush-systematix).

Comment: what is this error?
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dev_optfirst_contacts.id_contacts' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `dev_optfirst_contacts`.* FROM `dev_optfirst_contacts` WHERE (`dev_optfirst_contacts`.`id_contacts`='5324ca9f0f63211c1a13058553bdcd00')